# Delete a database with tables in Hive

Tags: database, hive, hiveql

I have a database in hive which has around 100 tables. I would like to delete the whole database in a single shot query.

How can we achieve that in Hive?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_drop_database.htm ?

Answer (score 30):

Use,

```
DROP DATABASE database_name CASCADE;
```

By default, the mode is `RESTRICT` which blocks the deletion of database if it holds tables.

Comment: Same situation, 2,414 tables. IT TAKES FOREVER and it's an external table supplied data by parquet. WHY DOES HIVE TAKE SO LONG TO DROP EXTERNAL DB CASCADE? Seriously, like 3 seconds per table dropped.

Comment: if you get an error `no viable alternative at input drop database` try putting backticks  around the name of the database. `DROP DATABASE \`database_name\` CASCADE;`

Answer (score 11):

You can use this command:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS HIVE_DATABASE_NAME CASCADE;
```

In case, you are using older version of Hive:
Drop all tables and views from hive database first, and then drop the database. You can consolidate below command in a shell script to execute.

```
hive -e 'use HIVE_DATABASE_NAME;show tables' | xargs -I '{}' hive -e 'use HIVE_DATABASE_NAME;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}'

hive -e 'use HIVE_DATABASE_NAME;show tables' | xargs -I '{}' hive -e 'use HIVE_DATABASE_NAME;DROP VIEW IF EXISTS {}'

hive -e 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS HIVE_DATABASE_NAME;'
```

Answer (score 7):

**General syntax is as follows:**

```
hive> DROP DATABASE [IF EXISTS] database_name [RESTRICT|CASCADE];
```

The default behaviour is RESTRICT, where DROP DATABASE will fail if the database is not empty. To drop the tables in the database as well, use DROP DATABASE … with CASCADE option.

***1. Drop database without table or Empty Database:***

```
hive> DROP DATABASE database_name;
```

***2. Drop database with tables:***

```
hive> DROP DATABASE database_name CASCADE;
```

It dropping respective tables before dropping the database.

Comment: any reason this operation takes 3 seconds per table, in serial when dropping a DB with 2,414 external tables (parquet locations)?